# Difference between Azure Microsot.Web/ serverFams vs hostingEnvironments

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I'm creating a new subnet to host an App Service and there are two Web options to "SUBNET DELEGATION":

- **Microsoft.Web/hostingEnvironments**
- **Microsoft.Web/serverFarms**

What is the difference between them?

Answer (score 1):

**Microsoft.Web hostingEnvironments**

- You can define [privateEndpointconnections](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.web/hostingenvironments/privateendpointconnections?tabs=json) and [workerPools](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.web/hostingenvironments/workerpools?tabs=json)
- hostingEnvironmentProfile - App Service Environment to use for the app.

**Microsoft.Web/serverFarms**

- You can define [gateways](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.web/serverfarms/virtualnetworkconnections/gateways?tabs=json) and [routes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.web/serverfarms/virtualnetworkconnections/routes?tabs=json).
- serverFarmId - Resource ID of the associated App Service plan, formatted as: "/subscriptions/{subscriptionID}/resourceGroups/{groupName}/providers/Microsoft.Web/serverfarms/{appServicePlanName}".

You can refer to [Microsoft.Web/serverFarms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30624293/why-is-a-microsoft-web-serverfarms-resource-required-for-hosting-a-website) and [Custom configuration settings for App Service Environments](https://github.com/uglide/azure-content/blob/master/articles/app-service-web/app-service-app-service-environment-custom-settings.md#custom-configuration-settings-for-app-service-environments)